# C++ Concurrency segfault on mutex

Tags: c++, concurrency, mutex, condition-variable

Hello,

i am quite new to C++ but I have 6 years Java experience, 2 years C experience and some knowledge of concurrency basics. I am trying to create a threadpool to handle tasks. it is below with the associated test main.

it seems like the error is generated from

```cpp
void ThreadPool::ThreadHandler::enqueueTask(void (*task)(void)) {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(queueMutex);
```

as said by my debugger, but doing traditional cout debug, i found out that sometimes it works without segfaulting and removing

```cpp
threads.emplace(handler->getSize(), handler);
```

from `ThreadPool::enqueueTask()` improves stability greatly.

Overall i think it is related too my bad use of condition_variable (called idler).

compiler: minGW-w64 in CLion

.cpp

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "ThreadPool.h"

ThreadPool::ThreadHandler::ThreadHandler(ThreadPool *parent) : parent(parent) {
    thread = std::thread([&]{
        while (this->parent->alive){
            if (getSize()){
                std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(queueMutex);
                (*(queue.front()))();
                queue.pop_front();
            } else {
                std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(idlerMutex);
                idler.wait(lock);
            }
        }
    });
}

void ThreadPool::ThreadHandler::enqueueTask(void (*task)(void)) {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(queueMutex);
    queue.push_back(task);
    idler.notify_all();
}

size_t ThreadPool::ThreadHandler::getSize() {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(queueMutex);
    return queue.size();
}

void ThreadPool::enqueueTask(void (*task)(void)) {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(threadsMutex);
    std::map<int, ThreadHandler*>::iterator iter = threads.begin();
    threads.erase(iter);
    ThreadHandler *handler = iter->second;
    handler->enqueueTask(task);
    threads.emplace(handler->getSize(), handler);
}

ThreadPool::ThreadPool(size_t size) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(threadsMutex);
        ThreadHandler *handler = new ThreadHandler(this);
        threads.emplace(handler->getSize(), handler);
    }
}

ThreadPool::~ThreadPool() {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(threadsMutex);
    auto it = threads.begin(), end = threads.end();
    for (; it != end; ++it) {
        delete it->second;
    }
}
```

.h

```cpp
#ifndef WLIB_THREADPOOL_H
#define WLIB_THREADPOOL_H

#include <mutex>
#include <thread>
#include <list>
#include <map>
#include <condition_variable>

class ThreadPool {
private:
    class ThreadHandler {
        std::condition_variable idler;
        std::mutex idlerMutex;
        std::mutex queueMutex;
        std::thread thread;
        std::list<void (*)(void)> queue;
        ThreadPool *parent;
    public:
        ThreadHandler(ThreadPool *parent);
        void enqueueTask(void (*task)(void));
        size_t getSize();
    };
    std::multimap<int, ThreadHandler*> threads;
    std::mutex threadsMutex;
public:
    bool alive = true;
    ThreadPool(size_t size);
    ~ThreadPool();

    virtual void enqueueTask(void (*task)(void));
};


#endif //WLIB_THREADPOOL_H
```

main:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <ThreadPool.h>

ThreadPool pool(3);

void fn() {
    std::cout << std::this_thread::get_id() << '\n';
    pool.enqueueTask(fn);
};

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;
    pool.enqueueTask(fn);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you aware that your example above would never terminate? The task always starts another task.

Comment: Are you sure the map `threads` is never empty? And why aren't you using [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) for the "function"?

Comment: @Steve yes, it is to test on a longer period of time.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg theads is sometimes empty, that is why I check for size, does it matter? for the function, i am more familiar with the C syntax.

Comment: `threads.erase(iter);` <- that invalidates `iter` you can't (safely) use it afterwards. Try: `iter = threads.erase(iter);` <- `iter` receives a new valid iterator or use it before calling `erase(iter)` with it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `main()` function invokes `enqueueTask()`.

Immediately afterwards, your `main()` returns.

This gets the gears in motion for winding down your process. This involves invoking the destructors of all global objects.

`ThreadPool`'s destructor then proceeds to delete all dynamically-scoped threads.

While the threads are still running. Hilarity ensues.

You need to implement the process for an orderly shutdown of all threads.

This means setting `active` to false, kicking all of the threads in the shins, and then joining all threads, before letting nature take its course, and finally destroy everything.

P.S. -- you need to fix how `alive` is being checked. You also need to make access to `alive` thread-safe, protected by a mutex. The problem is that the thread could be holding a lock on one of two differented mutexes. This makes this process somewhat complicated. Some redesign is in order, here.

Comment: indeed it is the destructor, thanks a lot, I didn't think it would have such an impact. why would a boolean need to be thread safe since it is only ever changed once to false, and reads/writes of primitives are instantaneous on the datatype,

Comment: "Thread safe" does not mean just "multiple updates from multiple threads are done in a thread safe manner", but also "well-defined semantics for updates from one thread, and reads from another thread". Only changes that occur while a mutex is being held are guaranteed to be visible to other threads after the mutex is released (with those other threads also holding a mutex, as well).

Comment: i still fail to see the use of that case, the architecture defines a task cycle which starts by checking the livelyhood of the parent, if it is live it does its thing, if not, it ends. i dont see how the performance reduction by the mutex gives any security, as it would result in an additional cycle... I won't spare one instruction if it works without...

Comment: The observable effects of one thread are not guaranteed to be visible to another thread,  unless they are "sequenced". A compiler sees "active=false;" in some function somewhere. Big freaking deal: the compiler sees that nothing else in the function reads "active", and there are no function calls, so it won't generate code to actually set the value until the function returns. This is allowed in C++.